# Type 'AutovalidateMode' not found

Tags: flutter

I am getting error while I am while SMS auto fill package in older version of flutter sdk 1.20.4
AutovalidateMode isn't a type.
AutovalidateMode AutovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode. Disabled,

Answer (score 0):

use mini  version of flutter sdk 2.0.0